# How to reattach flashing to the fascia board on a gable?

Tags: repair, metal, flashing

This piece fell from the front of our house and I need to get up there to nail it back into place. I do okay on ladders just not sure if my idea will work:

Fully extend the extension ladder and have a 160 pound friend stand on the bottom rung to provide weight. Climb up, nail, climb down.

Or if there is a better approach I’m open to it.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that putting all that weight on the gutter is such a good idea.

Comment: That ladder angle looks too shallow; 75° (or "4-1") so the feet don't kick out. I've seen it happen even with someone footing the ladder...

Comment: That would be a task using the extension with a ladder jack with a scaffold board long enough to rest on the ridge with protection for the ridge cap shingles. That's the only way I would do it, or a bucket lift.

Answer (score 1):

That will work for the first half of the board but from there to the peak you'll need something else. I'd then get up on the top roof lying down and extend my arms out with an electric screwdriver and some stainless steel screws and screw the rest of the board in place. This, of course, depends on how you are with heights.

Comment: This site should have a strict no roof advice policy. I know of two people personally who died falling doing roof work. I know a few more who have broken and shattered limbs from falling off roofs.

Comment: I understand your point, @RibaldEddie, yet every day 100s if not 1000s of people get up on roofs, do work, and come down safely. It's all about risk mitigation. Personally, I _hate_ doing anything hanging over the edge of the roof, as suggested - I'll stand on a 28' extension ladder or set up scaffold to do it, instead.

Comment: @FreeMan  Not suggesting hanging over the roof, just extending your reach, arms, over the edge for a couple of screws. Any larger jobs would use scaffolding.  I've climbed 65' power poles with hooks and a belt but half that height on an extension ladder would scare me.

Comment: @RibaldEddie  When we give out DIYer advise, we assume/hope the individual does a self assessment on their physical  abilities to do the task. If we were to have a strict no roof advise policy, we might as well have a strict no advise policy.  Most of our advise involved power tools, saws, jack hammers and extensive amounts of electrical work, all of which can be dangerous if the person isn't capable. Even the pros get hurt/killed on the job.

Comment: @JACK roofs are more dangerous than power tools imho.

Comment: Maybe find the truth somewhere in the middle? Feel free to suggest these things, as long as you also stringently warn of the risks (especially when death is an option). In this case I would also be concerned about roofing coming loose when you walk over it, or giving away because it's not sufficiently supported underneath.

Comment: I was also considering the possibility of making the ladder lean up against the facade (rather than the gutter) and stepping on the lower roof while holding the upper roof edge, then standing with feet on both slopes while continuing to hold on with one hand... but I don't know if both the lower roof and the ledges will hold. The risk as mentioned is rolling off, landing on your head and literally breaking your neck, so this is not something you should do when you're not 100% sure. Also, stepping off the ladder too briskly would push it away and have a similar result.